# How do I open the back of a gustavsberg toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Our toilet is flushing every 20 minutes, and it's visibly leaking into the pot. We live in Iceland, water is cheap here, but it's really annoying. Problem is, I can't seem to open it and it's plastic so I'm afraid to apply pressure.

It's similar to this one.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guestavsberg has product manuals available on their website:

- http://www.gustavsberg.com/28081.asp

Find the page for the specific toilet, then from the product's page, go to 'downloads' and look for the link labeled 'assembly', which also includes information about servicing it.

It looks like some of them have two bolts connecting in from underneath and then you can slip the whole cover off; others have round thing on the top that you press down then give a quarter turn and pull up.

Comment: Hey thanks man. Had to go through a couple of them assembly guides to find my exact system, but I found it. Any idea where I can get parts? Can't find any info on their homepage. It seems to be the rubber thing that plugs in the bottom, it's old and shrunk...

Comment: Sorry, no idea, but they've got to have parts available for the professionals to repair, so someone has to have them.  You might try [contacting them](http://www.gustavsberg.com/1342.asp) and asking if there are parts distributors in your area, or some place you can mail order from.